# How to change the attributes of only future text in an NSTextStorage?

Tags: swift, nstextview, nstextstorage

Good day,

i'll like to know how I can change the attributes of only future text in an NSTextStorage, setting the attributes of the textStorage changes all the text in the Text Storage not future text. if anyone could assist me with this. it would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSTextStorage is a subclass of NSMutableAttributedString. You can set the attributes for any range of characters using `setAttributes(_:range:)` and related methods. You can append and insert NSAttributedStrings (with their own attributes) using `append()` and `insert()`.

There are no "current" attributes in an NSMutableAttributedString. You assign attributes as part of the NSAttributedString you're adding. If you want to change the attributes of newly added text, then you will need to create NSAttributedStrings with those attributes.

If you're working with a (NS|UI)TextView or UITextField, you can use `typingAttributes` to set what attributes should be applied to new text, but this is handled at the UI layer, not the NSTextStorage layer. If you're making your own UI element, you'll need to handle this yourself.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much